# How to update PHP File paths for different deployment environments

Tags: php

I am looking to update file paths of model/controllers or for that matter even basic about.php to something without the .php extension like just about/, in the source-code, based on the environments.

Why? Don't want to reveal the actual paths and variables for security.

For Example:

When I call a delete_user controller in the DEV environment, currently the `href` in `<a>` tag is pointing to `delete_user.php` passing the User-ID as a GET variable. Then there is a controller which runs the DELETE SQL Query, and redirects back to the calling page.

```
<a href="delete_user.php?delete_user_id=<?= $row['user_id'] ?>" class="table-action table-action-delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete">
</a>
```

On Production Environment, I want the `href` to be instead as `delete-user/user-id`.

Now, the href file-paths should be updated and interpreted seamlessly across environments.

```
<a href="delete-user/<?= $row['user_id'] ?>" class="table-action table-action-delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete">
</a>
```

Environment: NGINX, PHP7.4 (LEMP)

What is the best and scalable way to achieve this in PHP?

Comment: You can use jenkins for this, no solution within PhP

Answer (score 0):

You can add environment variables in your php-fmp settings and read those in your code. This will depend on your server setup, so you can google what you need.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/setting-environment-variables-in-php-fpm

Then in your php you have access to those variables either using `$_ENV` or `getenv()`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

alternatively, there may be some field of the `$_SERVER` variable that can do what you need, but these will be specific to your setup so you need to `var_dump($_SERVER)` in your dev environment and in your prod environment and find a field that can work for you.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Yes, I thought of a similar approach of maintaining a variables file..and reading the values from that file. File will be custom for every environment. 

$_SERVER is also a good way. I currently use it to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I will consider three ways :

**The first one is involving that you can maintain a custom entity called ApplicationLinksConfiguration map for your various env.**

Properties :

- `$configKey` : universal key as text or integer, as you prefer
- `$testValue` : value for the test step env
- `$stagingValue` : value for the staging step env
- `$prodValue` : value for the prod final step env

And any other steps you need.

Of course you can add setters and getters and a custom constructor to build an object.

Of course you can add a factory system or any builder design pattern to simplify your links management as your config system.

**The second way to consider is that you can use your framework links builder system, if any.** As an example, when you are using `Zend Framework`, or `Laminas` which is the last version of that same framework, there are some view helpers which are responsible to build your links through all your webapplication.

There are of course [many view helpers](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-view/helpers/intro/), but the [url view helper](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-view/helpers/url/) can show you many advantages in a daily work basis. For static resources, there is the [asset view helper](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-view/helpers/asset/) too.

So, as there are different application statuses managed inside that framework, you can implement yours following the directives specified inside the official documentation, especially [this section and the next one](https://docs.laminas.dev/tutorials/advanced-config/#environment-specific-system-configuration).

Now you can build a custom `ApplicationLinksConfiguration` manager who is application mode aware, and write custom env with your custom rules to build your links like that : one env, one custom rule. Or one ring for hrefs, one ring to build all your your hrefs.

And the last way is to define custom routes for specific env and/or custom needs. `Laminas` is very handy for that too.

Have a good day.